# Comparing string columns in MySql for EntityFrameworkCore fails to generate proper SQL

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core, mysql-connector

I am using MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore version 6.10.1-beta to write the following LINQ query:

```
        var data = await _context
            .Assets
            .Where(a => string.Compare(a.Name, "b", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > 0)
            .Take(2)
            .ToListAsync();
```

where the 'Name' property is a string. In other words, I want to get the next 2 database entries that have a 'Name' property greater than 'b'.

The code works as expected from the outside but when I look at the generated SQL, I see the following:

```
SELECT `a`.`F_ASSET_PK`, `a`.`F_ASSET_TYPE`, `a`.`F_CREATION_TIME`, `a`.`F_ID`, `a`.`F_IS_SOFT_DELETED`, `a`.`F_LAST_MODIFIED_TIME`, `a`.`F_LIBRARY_ID`, `a`.`F_NAME`, `a`.`F_OWNER_ID`, `a`.`F_TENANT_ID`
FROM `accounting`.`T_ASSET` AS `a`
```

As you can see my LIMIT and WHERE clauses are not in the generated SQL. They are applied in memory causing sub-optimal performances.

If I remove my 'Where' in the C#, then the query is properly generated with the LIMIT. Therefore, as soon as I try to compare strings in my query through `string.Compare(a.Name, "b", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > 0`, the MySql driver gets confused and he fails to generate the proper SQL.

Is there another syntax that I could use to compare strings that would result in the proper SQL?

Note that I am using this with Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 1.1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to my own question:

Use `string.Compare(a.Name, "b") > 0` instead of `string.Compare(a.Name, "b", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > 0`.